# Loop inside a string in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I need some way to make a loop inside a function that I use to create a string.
The following code is inside a loop on that function.

```
{
 $messageBody .=
 $todayArray["responsibles"][273774][$reponsible].
 "\nAyer:\n"
  // I need to make a for loop for the next line
 .$yesterdayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$yesterdayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$yesterdayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\nImpedimentos:\n".$yesterdayArray["impediments"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n"
 ."Hoy:\n"
  // And for this line too
 .$todayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$todayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$todayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n";
}
```

As you can see I can't directly make the for loop because I'm in the middle of building a string.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break your single string creation into multiple parts, while concatenating to the same variable.

```
$messageBody .= "{$todayArray["responsibles"][273774][$reponsible]}\nAyer:\n";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { //loop 1
    $messageBody .= $yesterdayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$yesterdayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$yesterdayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\nImpedimentos:\n".$yesterdayArray["impediments"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n";
}

$messageBody .= "Hoy:\n";

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) { //loop 2
    $messageBody .= $todayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$todayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$todayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just terminate adding things where you need to loop and keep on concatenating while you are inside the loops. It should be obvious that the loops I included are just there for illustration purposes and don't do anything meaningful. Just plug in what you need where they are.

```
{
 $messageBody .=
 $todayArray["responsibles"][273774][$reponsible].
 "\nAyer:\n";
  // I need to make a for loop for the next line
  for ($a = 0;$a < 2;$a++) {
    $messageBody .=  $yesterdayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$yesterdayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$yesterdayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\nImpedimentos:\n".$yesterdayArray["impediments"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n";

  }
 $messageBody .= "Hoy:\n";

  for ($a = 0;$a < 2;$a++) {

  // And for this line too
    $messageBody .=  $todayArray["contents"][273774][$reponsible]."\n".$link.$todayArray["tasksid"][273774][$reponsible]." Procentaje completado:".$todayArray["progress"][273774][$reponsible]."\n\n";
  }
}
```